# Append String object to character array in Arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, string, arduino

I am using Arduino. I would like to append a String object to an array of characters.

```
String msg = "ddeeff"

char charArr[1600];

//assume charArr already contains some string
//How can I do something like this to append String to charArray?
charArr = charArr + msg;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for Arduino String object.

```
strcat( charArr, msg.c_str() );
```

String object `msg` gets converted into an array of characters with the String method c_str(). Then, you can use strcat() to append the 2 arrays of characters.

As mentioned by Rakete1111, it is undefined behavior if `charArr` is not big enough

Comment: Be careful though, it is undefined behavior if `charArr` is not big enough.

Comment: char charArr[1600]; might rather be too big for a "standard" Arduino UNO, depending on other local variable requirements etc. Be careful in that direction, too. Behavior is undefined as well.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

[`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) has a `operator+` which takes a `const char*`, and it also has a `c_str()` function, which converts it to a `const char*`.

You can combine them to get the desired result:

```
String temp = charrArr + msg; //Store result in a String

//Copy every character
std::strncpy(charArr, temp.c_str(), sizeof(charrArr));
```

Comment: Now charArr may not contain the terminating '\0'.